# Why Todo Item only save to localStorage when hit submit button two times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make simple Todo Apps with react and can save item on localStorage, but I must hit submit button two times to make saved to localStorage. So if we submit input 'Hello', then submit 'World', and will saved to localStorage is text 'Hello', how to make only hit 1 time the button?

[When We Submit, Before Reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfZL0.jpg),
[After Reload Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jil3s.jpg)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Todo.css";

const Todo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodo();
  }, []);

  const updateText = e => {
    setText(e.target.value);
    console.log(text);
  };

  const getTodo = () => {
    let todoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo")) || [];
    setTodo(todoLocal);
  };

  const saveTodo = (todo = {}) => {
    localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todo));
  };

  const fillTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

        setTodo(prevTodo => [
            ...prevTodo,
            {
              text: text
            }
        ]); 
    //localStorage.removeItem('todo');
    console.log(todo);
    saveTodo(todo);
  };

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <div className="title row">To-Do List</div>
      <div className="list">
        {todo.map((todoItem, index) => (
          <div className="row" key={index}>
            <input type="checkbox" data-index={index} />
            <p>{todoItem.text}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <form className="title row" onSubmit={fillTodo}>
        <input
          id="todo-input"
          type="text"
          value={text}
          placeholder="New Todo"
          onChange={updateText}
        />
        <button className="todo-submit">+ Todo</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't it be better if you think that storing in local storage is a side**Effect**

```
// syncs localStorage with the current todo value
React.useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todo));
}, [todo])
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing then I saw your answer. Since OP has a `saveTodo` method, maybe it can be used here but it is not necessary to have a separate method actually.

Comment: i do that, but make localStorage always only empty array, i thing the problem at `fillTodo` on `<form onSubmit={fillTodo}> .... </form>` , i must hit button to make it save to `todo` array state.